# Angular component is not opening

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a navbar with different components that have to open on selection. The profile components does open, but the "my favorite" button doesn't show anything from that component.

This is the code from the navbar:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a class="nav-link" [routerLink]= "['/favorites']">My favorites</a></li>
          <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a class="nav-link" [routerLink]= "['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a> </li>
          <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a class="nav-link" [routerLink]= "['/profile']">Profile</a></li>
          <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a class="nav-link" [routerLink]= "['/login']">Login</a></li>
          <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"> <a  class="nav-link"[routerLink]= "['/register']">Register</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" (click)="onLogOutClick()" href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </form>
```

I have these routes in my app.module.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'favorites', component: FavoritesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}

]
```

I can provide you with more code if necessary.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Is the component loaded in the DOM?

Comment: Can you also share your favorites component?

Comment: Please check what the browser console says. Could be that you have an error in your FavoriteComponent (ts and or html). The path seems to be correct, then check the DevTool your browsers.

Comment: I'm getting no errors whatsoever, that's why I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether your FavoritesComponent is included in the AppModule.ts file.

Comment: This should be a comment , not an answer

Comment: It is added to the AppModule.ts too, any other suggestions?

Comment: Try to load the favorites component without routing i.e. on the home page itself. If that works fine, then maybe you need some change in your routing part. If not, then its your favorites component that needs to be fixed.